# Unicode file name testbed

Tags: c++, testing, unicode

I have a C++ application which uses Unicode file names in different languages (writes them in a database). Is there a testbed with file names in different languages (using specific characters to that language) which I can use to test my application?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt what you want exists, but you could use something like the wikipedia article of [countries and capitals in native languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_capitals_in_native_languages). You'll have to do some copy-pasting, but there's a variety of scripts represented, all in unicode.